How to get rid of the WEBP format entirely in all browsers?
Websites keep serving more and more images in the WEBP format, this is getting worse with Cloudflare's Image Optimization service. This format is extremely problematic for me and many users, because it doesn't work with a ton of graphic editing programs, can't be uploaded back on many websites, thumbnails don't work with it in file explorers, and in most cases it behaves like an arbitrary binary blob, not an image. That's why I'd like to only load it as last resort, where there are definitely no other formats available.
In most cases, normal image formats like JPG or PNG are actually available, it's just that CDNs or websites decide to serve WEBP, because otherwise they're punished by Google. There are many cases where an image with a .png or .jpg extension as visible in the URL, is actually a WEBP, and you only find out (or not!) when downloading it!
I searched a lot for solutions to this problem, and as far as I can tell there is nothing definitive. I would like this question to be the ultimate web resource on solutions, so I will list what I tried and did NOT work to my satisfaction, and hopefully at some point future Google searches will lead to this question (and a possible answer).
Here's what I'd like to achieve: a mechanism built into the browser, that works for as many browsers as possible, that automatically requests all the image files in normal image formats like JPG, PNG, or GIF, lets you display them and save them without conversion, and only uses WEBP when there is no other way to display or download the image.
Here are the solutions I tried or considered:

Don't Accept WEBP - this is an extension, sadly only available for Firefox
Simple Modify Headers - a header modifier, which allows you to remove image/webp format from the accepted list. Very limited, doesn't work with multiple URLs. Though it fixes reddit's forced HTML page that's being served instead of images (that's a different problem).
Accept header - I know of no native mechanism in any browser that would let me modify it. I also know of no switches in the settings of any browser that let you do this.
Various conversion plugins - There are browser extensions available that let you convert downloaded images. This is a subpar solution - the quality gets hit by first being served as WEBP, then being converted to a normal image format.
wget/curl - these programs can usually download the "real" image, but that adds another step to the process. I'd like it to be built into the browser.
URL tricks - e.g. add a ? at the end of the URL - this is CDN/website specific, and doesn't work in all cases, it can also stop working at any time.


the webp format is a form of DRM

No, it's not a form of DRM.

This question is relevant. Why the downvotes?

A specific solution is required per browser.
An extension for Chrome :
Save image as Type.

As far as I can tell, this extension is a converter.

+1 because the question tries to circumvent DRM so a converter is the logical solution.

@RuslanOblov: And what else do you expect when you ask for a format which the server doesn't publish?

I don't think you understood my question... I explicitly ruled out converters. WEBP is also definitely NOT a form of DRM, so that's a mischaracterization.

@RuslanOblov: Again, how do you think to force the website or Cloudflare to do anything else than what they normally do, when even a headers modify extension only worked for a limited number of websites that paid it some attention?

By setting the Accept headers to exclude image/webp everywhere. Did you read my question?

Your question says "How to get rid of the WEBP format entirely in all browsers?" If you wanted to ask "How to get rid of image/webp entirely in all browser accept requests?" then you should have said so to start with, not downvoted people who only tried to help.

I can accept other solutions, if they exist. If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't have asked in the first place.

Magic solutions don't exist, some solutions may work with some browsers and some websites, but that's all. I always convert webp and it it's no problem.
